# Prompted \read input when there should be none

Tags: conditionals

I can't understand how `\read# to \sth` or `\ifeof` are supposed to work. If an stream not in [0,15] is used, or the stream is closed, or doesn't exist, it will prompt you to manually input the num if you're running the .tex in a console. Otherwise, you get error and it breaks the documents on the spot, in my case- doesn't print out the rest of the longtable.

The MWE kind of simulates the case. Data gets read from a file, 2 rows at a time, a beginning and ending date. In the original these get compared to the current date row's date and if there's a match it begins to `\immediate\write` to a data file until the 2. date is match, then it stops, closes output stream, and this happens for each pair of dates- here it should be a simple overwriting of `\aaaaa and \bbbbb` since that's enough to reproduce the error.

A few places in the original code contain `\ifeof`, it's like I can never get it to go to the true branch. In the MWE the T-branch doesn't execute either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{
    etoolbox,
    xstring,
}
\newcounter{foo}
\newbool{hasReadPeriod}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\periods
\immediate\openout\periods=1.dat
\def\mynum{6}
\def\testi{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    \immediate\write\periods{0000-00-\thefoo}%
    \ifnum\thefoo=\mynum
    \else
        \testi{}%
    \fi
}

\testi{} Test 1: write \mynum{} rows + 1 empty.\par \vspace*{0.25cm}\hrule\vspace*{0.25cm}
\immediate\closeout\periods


\newread\periods
\openin\periods=1.dat
\setcounter{foo}{0}


Test 2: step counter foo, read 2 rows from file on odd numbers
\def\testii{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    \thefoo%
    \ifeof\periods
        this never shows up, why?
        \closein\periods% does nothing
    \else
        \ifbool{hasReadPeriod}%
            {%  
                . F\quad%
                \global\boolfalse{hasReadPeriod}%
                b5 = \bbbbb%
            }%
            {%
                \global\read\periods to \aaaaa%
                \global\read\periods to \bbbbb%
                \global\booltrue{hasReadPeriod}%
                . T\quad%
                a5 = \aaaaa%
            }%
    \fi
    %
    \ifnum\thefoo=\mynum
        \quad LAST ROW%
    \fi
    %
    \par
}

\testii{}\testii{}\testii{}
\testii{}\testii{}\testii{}
% \testii{}% COMMENT ME OUT OR WON'T BUILD (WO/ MAN. INPUT)
\end{document}
```

*edit*: `\global`s are because the respective things in the main don't get read or written, or T/F'd, it's in a longtable. Don't know how much that matters in the example, but given that it's inside a command, I'd rather make sure.

Comment: you could remove geometry and fontspec which are irrelevant to this but force xetex to be used.

Comment: note however that `\ifnum\thefoo=\mynum` is a very unsafe test as `\mynum` is defined by `\def\mynum{6}` which does not terminate the number so the `\else` branch will be expanded early.

Comment: In the main, the read line is a string which gets compared via `\ifx` to an `\xdef`'d date made of `\the<counters>`. Should be beside the point, getting the same error/prompt. Please elaborate what a terminated number is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
                \global\read\periods to \aaaaa%
\show\aaaaa
```

then you will see on the terminal

```
> \aaaaa=macro:
->0000-00-3 .
<argument> ...ead \periods to \aaaaa \show \aaaaa 
                                                  \global \read \periods to ...
l.65 \testii{}\testii{}\testii
                              {}
? 
> \aaaaa=macro:
->0000-00-5 .
<argument> ...ead \periods to \aaaaa \show \aaaaa 
                                                  \global \read \periods to ...
l.66 \testii{}\testii
                     {}\testii{}
? 
> \aaaaa=macro:
->\par .
```

So on the last line `\aaaaa` is `\par` but you do two `\read` so step off the end.

so you could test for that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{
    etoolbox,
    xstring,
}

\newcounter{foo}
\newbool{hasReadPeriod}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\periods
\immediate\openout\periods=1.dat
\def\mynum{6}
\def\testi{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    \immediate\write\periods{0000-00-\thefoo}%
    \ifnum\thefoo=\mynum
    \else
        \testi{}%
    \fi
}

\testi{} Test 1: write \mynum{} rows + 1 empty.\par \vspace*{0.25cm}\hrule\vspace*{0.25cm}
\immediate\closeout\periods


\newread\periods
\openin\periods=1.dat
\setcounter{foo}{0}

\def\endpar{\par}
Test 2: step counter foo, read 2 rows from file on odd numbers
\def\testii{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    \thefoo%
    \ifeof\periods
        this never shows up, why?
        \closein\periods% does nothing
    \else
        \ifbool{hasReadPeriod}%
            {%  
                . F\quad%
                \global\boolfalse{hasReadPeriod}%  why all the \global????
                b5 = \bbbbb%
            }%
            {%
                \global\read\periods to \aaaaa%
\ifx\aaaaa\endpar\else
                \global\read\periods to \bbbbb%
                \global\booltrue{hasReadPeriod}%
                . T\quad%
                a5 = \aaaaa%
\fi
            }%
    \fi
    %
    \ifnum\thefoo=\mynum
        \quad LAST ROW%
    \fi
    %
    \par
}

\testii{}\testii{}\testii{}
\testii{}\testii{}\testii{}
\testii{}% COMMENT ME OUT OR WON'T BUILD (WO/ MAN. INPUT)
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, basically, a check after the first `\read` if it's a `\par` to see if any more should be read. 
Why doesn't the `\ifeof` every go true? I want to see when the `{\HUGE EOF}` appears, I don't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: @vlg `\ifeof` isn't true until you get to the end of the file but since you read two lines at a time you need to check after the final aaa before reading bbb, add another `\testii` and you'll see it is now end of file